# Write data to json file with nextjs after build

Tags: node.js, json, next.js

I have a `json file` containing some basic site settings , which can be changed from an admin panel. I import these settings from the json file no problem, but writing to the file (updating the settings) seems to be a problem. I don't know where to put the file so I can write to it. I started off by putting the file to the `/public` folder, but then I learned that after build that folder becomes read only. Also tried putting the file in the project root but same thing occured. I can't write to it, because it's read only. Where should I place the file so I can write to it?